Ошибка Google Play Console: Не удалось подтвердить ваш номер телефона. Повторите попытку позже
Я прохожу процедуру верификации учетной записи разработчика Google Play Console. Верификация учетной записи требуется для всех существующих разработчиков Google Play, которые создали свою учетную запись Play Console до сентября 2023 года. В контактной информации я правильно ввел номер телефона, код страны, но появляется ошибка: Не удалось подтвердить ваш номер телефона. Повторите попытку позже. Пожалуйста, помогите мне решить эту проблему?

Какой оператор у вас.

У меня оператор Мегафон, с ним у меня проблема, появляется ошибка: Не удалось подтвердить ваш номер телефона. Повторите попытку позже. Какой оператор порекомендуете использовать? Лучше проходить проверку через телефон или браузер? Если браузер, то какой использовать?

Посоветовать с оператором не могу. Но явно попробуйте другой. VPN используете? Попробуйте с ним.

Столкнулся сегодня с такой же проблемой, два телефона от Мегафона не прошли, но зато прошел номер от Теле2. Попробуйте использовать номер другого оператора.

Подтверждаю, на номер мегафона и йоты не удалось подтвердить, поменял оператора и получилось.

"поменял оператора и получилось"  если вас не затруднит, уточните на какого оператора вы поменяли?
